# Change SAPUI5 list item binding dynamically at design time using i18n file

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

I developed a list which works fine:

```
        <List
            id="list"
            items="{
               path: '/BusinessPartnerSet',
                sorter: {
                    path:'BusinessPartnerID',
                    descending: false
                },
                groupHeaderFactory: '.createGroupHeader'
            }"
            busyIndicatorDelay="{masterView>/delay}"
            noDataText="{masterView>/noDataText}"
            mode="{= ${device>/system/phone} ? 'None' : 'SingleSelectMaster'}"
            growing="true"
            growingScrollToLoad="true"
            updateFinished="onUpdateFinished"
            selectionChange="onSelectionChange">
            <infoToolbar>
                <Toolbar
                    active="true"
                    id="filterBar"
                    visible="{masterView>/isFilterBarVisible}"
                    press="onOpenViewSettings">
                    <Title
                        id="filterBarLabel"
                        text="{masterView>/filterBarLabel}" />
                </Toolbar>
            </infoToolbar>
            <items> ...
```

---

I would like to change the Item binding ( path: '/BusinessPartnerSet', ...) and taking the path from i18n.
I added a property to i18n file:
masterEntetySet=/BusinessPartnerSet
and changed the view code as following:

```
<List
            id="list"
            items="{
               path: '{i18n>masterEntetySet}',
                sorter: {
                    path:'BusinessPartnerID',
                    descending: false
                },
                groupHeaderFactory: '.createGroupHeader'
            }"
            busyIndicatorDelay="{masterView>/delay}"
            noDataText="{masterView>/noDataText}" ...
```

But it does not work.
How should I do this change correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like this. You should do element binding, more or less as explained here [SAPUI5 Dynamic Databinding (Key for OData-Service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188215/sapui5-dynamic-databinding-key-for-odata-service/51204752#51204752)

With one small change. When setting the path, get it from the i18n model

`this.getView().getModel("i18n").getProperty("masterEntetySet")`

However I wouldn't recommend you to do this, as i18n is not for storing paths, but readable, translatable texts. It could lead into problems if you ask a translator with no technical knowledge to translate your i18n files, and he/she translate also your path.